# DIV equivalent HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, header

I am trying to redo the a tutorial I had posted links to in previous question to have as much HTML5 and CSS3 code. I read in some online article's that in HTML5 they are trying to get rid of the idea of Div tags, rather they are pushing for something known as section. Is that a correct observation. For example I have this section of code from the above tutorial. 
https://skitch.com/android86/r67ey/dreamweaver
and what I am interested to know if I should be using div tags in my HTML5 code as well or is there a better way to do it rather than using Div's? 
What I have in my HTML5 code at present is the following. 
https://skitch.com/android86/r67ej/dreamweaver
Thanks for the group's valuable input.

Comment: There is no such thing in html5 ... what you are looking for is jQuery : jqueryui.com to be precise. Why would it no suffice ? Also, why html5 ? Html5 is not a scripting langage, which is something you would need to animate.

Answer (score 1):

a proof of concept for a sliding link over content (with `display: block`) on hover, using CSS3 transitions only.
NOTICE: this is a webkit (safari & chrome) only syntax, for the syntax for the rest of the browsers go here: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/
a simple  element, with the following style:

```
a {
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px; }
```

and the hover state style:

```
a:hover { height: 700px; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will look into the CSS3 usage :)

Answer (score 1):

The code submitted looks good, however I would include the extra lines to cover Firefox and Opera.

```
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

You can then use Modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/) to cover all browsers with backup Javascript.

I would use something like this:

```
    a.slideDown {
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    -webkit-transition: top .2s ease;
    -moz-transition: top .2s ease;
    -o-transition: top .2s ease;
    transition: top .2s ease;
    top:5px;

}  

a:hover.slideDown {
top:495px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are including CSS3 as part of HTML5 (which you have to to allow animation!), have a look at: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/sliding/ . The jQuery isn't necessary, you could use the :target pseudo element instead.

For your case, just set a transition on the element, then change the height, or top value using the target selector.

It's probably around 4 lines of code if you only want it to work in newer browsers.

Comment: Hi Rich - I read some great stuff on your website. I am wondering if there is a on click property which can be used. I could get the a:hover working based on the help by you guys but couldn't find anywhere online if there is a way to have onclick without using javascript. This is one example of on-click they said they were using CSS3, but they did end up using javascript. http://www.webdesignforums.net/threads/css3-transitions-and-onclick.31784/

Comment: You can use the :target pseudo selector, but not both ways really. I'd still use to toggle states, the animation is still much smoother.

Comment: When I have some time, I'll put up a demo showing what that does, as well as making a table describing the pros and cons of various techniques.

Comment: To clarify, the target selector probably isn't adequate for use in this way, and binding an event to a click is the way to go. Javascript isn't evil!

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with the comments about using CSS3 for transitions. I used this on a portfolio site and it looks fairly good. It's just a couple lines of code and if the browser doesn't support the transitions it will still display the content on hover, just without the animation.